# Why variable in docker is empty?

Tags: docker

I try to pass env variable into my docker container and then print it

```
docker exec -e VAR1=1 backend echo $VAR1
```

But in this case I get an empty output. Why variable is not set into container?

Comment: `$VAR1` is being expanded in your local shell, not in the docker container. Try `docker exec -e VAR1=1 backend sh -c 'echo $VAR1'`.

Comment: can you try this     docker exec -e VAR1=1 backend | grep VAR

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from official docker documentation.
COMMAND should be executable, a chained or a quoted command will not work. Example: `docker exec -ti my_container "echo a && echo b"` will not work, but `docker exec -ti my_container sh -c "echo a && echo b"` will.
https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/exec/